# how to tell vb net to read a number as different number

Tags: vb.net

This may sound like an odd question, but I'll ask anyways because I'm out of options.

I'm trying to create a Web application where it will get data from my database based on period in my company. In this example, Period 1 = April. So far I managed to get the application to obtain data for April when I key in 4 in my search field, the PeriodFrom textbox.

However, now I want it to show the result for April when I key in 1 in my search field, 2 will display May results and so on.

I tried using this code:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dsGROUP As New DataSet()
    Dim PFrom

    If PeriodFrom.Text = 1 Then
        PFrom = 4
        PeriodFrom.Text = PFrom
    End If

    Dim strSelectCmd As String = "select * from database where month(key_open) = '" & PFrom & "' and year(key_open) = '2017'         

Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(strSelectCmd, conn)
    ' Open the connection 
    cmd.Connection = conn

    conn.Open()
    da.Fill(dsGROUP, "testdb")

    ' Get the DataView  
    Dim dvGROUP As DataView = dsGROUP.Tables("testdb").DefaultView

    ' Bind the GridView control. 
    GridView1.DataSource = dvGROUP
    GridView1.DataBind()

    'End Using
    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

By doing so, when I key in 1 it will show me April's results when I click the button. But the value will change to 4 every time. Is there a way for the value to remain as 1 while displaying April data?

Comment: `PFrom = Int32.Parse(PeriodFrom.Text)
PFrom += 3`

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks a million. You're a lifesaver. Although I wonder does this work for  March as well? Example, Period is 12 in order to get March data.

Comment: `PFrom = (PFrom + 3) Mod 12`

Comment: OK. Thank you. If you haven't realize it yet, I'm a complete rookie with programming.

Answer (score 2):

You want to add an offset to your month and also handle the case that 12 means march. Use `Mod`

```
Dim offset As Int32 = 3
Dim PFrom  as Int32 = Int32.Parse(PeriodFrom.Text)
PFrom = (PFrom + offset) Mod 12
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the perfect place to use the 'Select Case' structure:

```
Dim PFrom As Integer

Select Case PeriodFrom.Text
    Case 1:PFrom = 4 'Apr
    Case 2:PFrom = 5 'May
    Case 3:PFrom = 6 'Jun
    Case 4:PFrom = 7 'Jul
    Case 5:PFrom = 8 'Aug
    Case 6:PFrom = 9 'Sep
    Case 7:PFrom = 10 'Oct
    Case 8:PFrom = 11 'Nov
    Case 9:PFrom = 12 'Dec
    Case 10:PFrom = 1 'Jan
    Case 11:PFrom = 2 'Feb
    Case 12:PFrom = 3 'Mar
End Select

MsgBox "Period From: " & Cstr(PFrom)
```

Also, just as a  side note, you have Dim'd 'PFrom' without a type, meaning it will be a variant and inefficient here.  I would dim it as an Integer in this case.

Comment: I'd prefer to use a `Dictionary` to do a mapping like this, rather than coding it into a `Select Case` block.

Comment: But what if year is involved? If I want to search for period 12 2017, which is March 2018 for example, it will just get the value in my Year textbox of 2017 and give me March 2017 instead of 2018.

Comment: If year is involved, you will need to tell it somehow.  Do you have a combobox you could put the years into?  You could then concatenate the PFrom period with the combobox year value.